Why doesn't a part separated from an accelerated body accelerate anymore?
Suppose, a force $F$ is applied on a body of mass $m$ for which it gains acceleration $a$. So, in this condition every single point (Considering only atoms and molecules) has the acceleration $a$.
But the whole thing isn't simple enough when a part of the body is separated for any reason. It's not accelerating anymore while a moment ago it was accelerating. Now it continues to move with the constant velocity which is the same of the body at the moment of separation.
Why is it like this way? Why doesn't the separated part keep accelerating?

Have you heard of the the first law of Newton? No force, no acceleration

@PatoGalmarini Then why does the first body keep accelerating?

because it is still feeling a force (second law of newton). It is two different objects now

@PatoGalmarini Can you tell why does something feel force? What you are saying is incomplete

May be your description is incomplete, what object, what kind fo force? where is it applied?

This depends on how the force is applied to the body. If it is a force field acting on all parts of the body, then what you write is not true. Then there will still be force on the separated part.
If, conversely, the force is applied on some point of the body, and that point is not inside the part that is split off, then the split off part is no longer accelerated, but then the reason for it is clear.

Okay I also thought the same reason. But what I see in most of the cases the later is assumed without mentioning if the force is uniform in all parts of the body or where the force is applied. Is it all about simplification?

You should only read reliable, unsimplified sources, like Physics SE :‑J
